# Refused to connect to ... because it violates the following CSP directive

Tags: c#, google-chrome, blazor, blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

I have a Blazor server-side and I added the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="base-uri 'self';
               default-src 'self';
               img-src data: https:;
               object-src 'none';
               script-src 'self';
               style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
               upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:58126/c5f3e2f1da1843188844fd8515c3ca3b/browserLinkSignalR/negotiate?requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44350%2FDashboard&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F109.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=2655-11e6&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1675268211057' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and

> Refused to connect to 'wss://localhost:44393/KeyAccount.Web/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Well, this might help with your web socket one, if not the signal r one https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-6-hot-reload-and-refused-to-connect-to-ws-because-it-violates-the-content-security-policy-directive-because-web-sockets

Comment: upvoted -  have the same problem, cannot seem to find any workaround...

Comment: So explicitly set `connect-src` to something other than `'self'`? (like `'http://localhost:58126' 'wss://localhost:44393'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Content security policy is a cach all for potential security bugs in your code. It disables part of the browser functionality you know you will not use. In your case the csp (The default from the Microsoft docs `¯\(°_o)/¯`) disables to much.

I got the same errors and updated my csp to the version below. I should disable more to be effective.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="base-uri 'self';
           default-src 'self';
           connect-src * ws: http: https: 'self';
           img-src data: https:;
           object-src 'none';
           script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
           style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
           upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```